# how to run a static site on bitnami and AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, cloud, hosting, bitnami

I am quite a noob when it comes to cloud based apps, this is a completely new context for me. I currently got the [github](http://education.github.com) education pack, part of it was an account on bitnami. I was wondering if it's possible to host a static html site on bitnami, I tried a few things but so far I got no where. I know that i can deploy a wordpress or drupal instance and then I can configure a theme for those, but I just want a simple static html site to run. Any guidance on how I can do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To host static website using Bitnami try following steps.

1. Run an AWS instance from marketplace using 'LAMP Stack powered by Bitnami' AMI. This AMI will have pre-configured LAMP stack.
2. Attach EIP to your Instance
3. Upload you website files to /var/www/html/
4. Type your EIP in browser and if everything went right you should be able to see your website.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want a static website on Bitnami or it could be in another platform?
Because you could host one on [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com). Just follow the guide.

Comment: I am aware about the github pages, but I am interested in finding out about this platform specifically; thank you tho!

Answer (score 0):

To host a super fast static site using a bitnami provided image I would use an nginx based stack such as: https://wiki.bitnami.com/Infrastructure_Stacks/Bitnami_Nginx_Stack

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out! ngnix was very helpful during the my initial trials! i ended deploying a rails app that spits out static pages, using unicorn and nginx.